# Math: What is the Equation that on increasing the integer x returns an alternate of 0 and 1?

Tags: math, equation

What is the Equation that on increasing the integer x returns an alternate of 0 and 1

example

x = 22

result 1

x = 23

result 0

x = 24

result 1

Comment: You can't return something "on increasing a value", what is it you're trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the example data, it would be modulo 2.  Assuming `x` is an int (and C/C++/C#):

```
(x + 1) % 2;
```

Comment: @phant0m:  Yes, thanks.  I figured that out a 3%2 milliseconds after I hit the OK button the first time.

Answer (score 3):

In C or C++ this would be

```
int y = (x+1)%2;
```

mathematically,

```
y = (x+1) modulo 2
```

Answer (score 2):

It's called [**modulo**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). You can use mod by `2` after adding one in the value.

```
   x = 22
   result = (x+1) modulo 2
```

In programming languages, it's often called `%`:

```
 x = 22
 result = (x+1) % 2    //<< result 1

 x = 23
 result = (x+1) % 2    //<< result 0
```

and so on..

Comment: Not the downvoter. This complies with the description but not with the example given (you're off by 1)

Comment: @JanDvorak: I jumped on `modulo`. Corrected the answer.

Comment: @JanDvorak You are really fast :) I corrected  while you were typing.

Comment: That could be because I'm writing with a Dvorak keyboard.